# How to split file based on first character in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, file, awk, split

I do have a fixedwidth flatfile with the header and detail data. Both of them can be recognized by the first character: 1 for header and 2 for detail.

I want to genrate 2 different files from my fixedwidth file , each file having it's own record set, but without type record written.

File Header.txt having only type 1 records.
File Detail.txt having only type 2 records.

Please Let me know how we can achieve this.

**Example flatfile:**

```
120190301,025712,FRANK,DURAND,USA
20257120023.12
20257120000.21
20257120191.45
120190301,025737,ERICK,SMITH,USA
20257370000.29
20257370326.41
120190301,025632,JOSEPH,SILVA,USA
20256320019.57
20256320029.12
20256320129.04
```

**Desired Outputs:**

***Header.txt***

```
20190301,025712,FRANK,DURAND,USA
20190301,025737,ERICK,SMITH,USA
20190301,025632,JOSEPH,SILVA,USA
```

***Detail.txt***

```
0257120023.12
0257120000.21
0257120191.45
0257370000.29
0257370326.41
0256320019.57
0256320029.12
0256320129.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This first one is gawk-specific and works because in gawk "If the value [of FS] is the null string (""), then each character in the record becomes a separate field."

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=""; f[1]="header.txt"; f[2]="detail.txt"}
       {i=$1; sub(/^./,""); print > f[i]}' file

$ cat header.txt
20190301,025712,FRANK,DURAND,USA
20190301,025737,ERICK,SMITH,USA
20190301,025632,JOSEPH,SILVA,USA

$ cat detail.txt
0257120023.12
0257120000.21
0257120191.45
0257370000.29
0257370326.41
0256320019.57
0256320029.12
```

One that should work with any awk:

```
$ awk '/^1/ {f="header.txt"}
       /^2/ {f="detail.txt"}
      {sub(/^./,""); print > f}' file
```

Comment: Nice - I like this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{if(/^1/){ sub(/^./,""); print > "Header.txt" }else{sub(/^./,""); print>"Detail.txt"}}' flatfile
```

If the first character of a line matches `1`, strip the first character and write the line to `Header.txt`, otherwise strip the first character and write the line to `Detail.txt`.

Outputs:

```
cat Header.txt 
20190301,025712,FRANK,DURAND,USA
20190301,025737,ERICK,SMITH,USA
20190301,025632,JOSEPH,SILVA,USA
```

And number two:

```
cat Detail.txt 
0257120023.12
0257120000.21
0257120191.45
0257370000.29
0257370326.41
0256320019.57
0256320029.12
0256320129.04
```

Comment: Thanks too much !

Answer (score 1):

To reduce IO, it redirect multi files to use "tee" command.

```sh
$ tee <All.txt >/dev/null \
  >(sed -n '/^1/s/^1//p' >Header.txt) \
  >(sed -n '/^2/s/^2//p' >Detail.txt)

$ cat Header.txt
20190301,025712,FRANK,DURAND,USA
20190301,025737,ERICK,SMITH,USA
20190301,025632,JOSEPH,SILVA,USA

$ cat Detail.txt
0257120023.12
0257120000.21
0257120191.45
0257370000.29
0257370326.41
0256320019.57
0256320029.12
0256320129.04
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this obviously didn't compare the output here to the output the OP desired.

Comment: Thanks too much !